# Google Maps Dynamic Search Query Webservice with JSON

Tags: web-services, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I wish to replicate the dynamic search results returned when entering in a location google maps for example, I'm from Sydney Australia so when I bring up Maps and type "Kin" I get:

[Maps Example http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/2042/screenshot20101215at514.png](http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/2042/screenshot20101215at514.png).

But if I use the Geocoder webservice with a string example like:

http://maps.google.com.au/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Kin+,%20Australia&bounds=-46.08542,-4.39023%7C93.33984,157.67578&sensor=false&region=au

OR

http://maps.google.com.au/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Kin&sensor=false

OR

http://maps.google.com.au/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Kin&sensor=false&region=au

All I get returned is (Try it yourself):

Kinshasa, Democratic Republic of the Congo
Arrivals (KIN), Kingston, Jamaica
4920 Kin, Belgium

ETC.

The one that attempts to limit it to australia returns only:

King Island, Loorana TAS 7256, Australia

Now I don't mind filtering the type to locality from the clientside, but why can't I get the EXACT same results as the Dynamic Search results returned from google maps itself.

Any help Most Appreciated! I've spent too long on this now...

Answer (score 1):

The Geocoder is for resolving a valid address to a location on the surface of the Earth. It is not intended for use as a suggestions / auto-complete service.

Comment: Yea, you're right, do you know if there exists a way to perform a Dynamic Search? Or Do you think Google doesn't want to be flooded with tons of TCP connections for every keystroke?

Answer (score 0):

I did this with jquery

// jquery autocompleta
$(function() {
    $("#address").autocomplete({
      //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
      source: function(request, response) {
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
          response($.map(results, function(item) {
            return {
              label:  item.formatted_address,
              value: item.formatted_address,
              latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
              longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
            }
          }));
        })
      },
      //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
      select: function(event, ui) {
        //$("#latitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
        //$("#longitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
        //var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
        //marker.setPosition(location);
        //map.setCenter(location);
      }
    });
});

address is a textfield in the html file